# Use PHP change link address in html source code

Tags: php, proxy

*Heya Thanks for checking me out*

[---Php Code---](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/743035131543027743/878722264605003806/UltraSmallProxy_1.php)

Right now trying to learn how to code in php, to fix a simple Url proxy, it simply works by putting the url after [www.Proxy.info/?u=](http://www.Proxy.info/?u=) and all works fine, except it doesn't change the embedded file paths

So In source code of the website im trying to proxy I have an address like this `/images/image.jpg` or `https://Somesite.com/js/file.js` and causes issue as the now proxied site thinks i have the file on my server

i need to add to my proxy server address ([www.Proxy.info/?u=](http://www.Proxy.info/?u=)) so it will use the now proxied sites file and make it work, like `http://www.Proxy.info/?u=/images/image.jpg` or `http://www.Proxy.info/?u=https://Somesite.com/js/file.js`

there is a proxy that does [this](https://womginx.synricha.org/), but it's using nginx, and i dont really like nginx, here is a second example, a little simple

i have it as

```
https://www.proxy.info/lib/fonts/source-code-pro-v14-latin-regular.woff2
```

but i need it as

```
https://www.proxy.info/?u=https://www.Somesite.com/lib/fonts/source-code-pro-v14-latin-regular.woff2
```

Or

```
https://www.Proxy.info/?u=Somesite.com/lib/fonts/source-code-pro-v14-latin-regular.woff2
```

If you can edit my code to fix that will be best as im very bad adding code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `html form` then set form method `GET` and input field `name="u"` and use php `$_GET['u']` to catch query url. It's was my comment but can't comment now. Also you didn't shared php codes, for that not fully sure where have to add/make changes. Plz update your post/codes.

**Updated Answer:**

As i see that you r using this github open source: [php-ultra-small-proxy](https://github.com/szczyglis-dev/php-ultra-small-proxy)

Use this full code in `index.php`:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
include __DIR__.'/UltraSmallProxy.php';

if(isset($_GET['u']))
{
    $url = $_GET['u'];
    $proxy = new UltraSmallProxy();
    $output = $proxy->load($url); // <-- specify start page here

    echo $output;
}
?>

<form method="GET">
    <input type="url" name="u" placeholder="Enter proxy visit url" required>
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

I used `isset() Function` to check whether a variable is empty/set/declared. Another thing is `$_GET`, its a php super global variable and parameters is `u`. Adding this super global variable and parameters you will get like this (`https://www.proxy.info/?u=https://www.Somesite.com/lib/fonts/source-code-pro-v14-latin-regular.woff2`) get request url.

Comment: @Hacker I updated answer, If its solve your problem, then plz mark my answer as solved by clicking tick mark button. thanks

Comment: Ah man im having issues with adding the code, can you send the file with the code

Comment: Download: `https://file.io/ng7K3wwCWbSi` then unzip

Comment: *The file you requested has been deleted*

Comment: Damn, i get this error in my web hoster
|
Warning: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in /storage/ssd3/725/17428725/public_html/index.php on line 2

Comment: remove this line `set_time_limit(0);` from index.php

Comment: Ah still not working right, if you want i can link you to my site and you can test it

Comment: Remove index.php code and add this code: https://rentry.co/3odiz

Comment: i did on the site and im getting a redirecting issue

Comment: add `exit();` under header()

Comment: use previous this `www89.zippyshare.com/v/wlbQ34Dv/file.html` code, actually i don't understand clearly what you wanted to do

Comment: do you have discord, it will make this easier

Comment: sent and you can edit your comment to hide your discord tag